# Importing existing microsoft reports into foxpro database

Tags: reportviewer, rdlc, foxpro

Is it possible to import existing reports designed in Microsoft reportviewer (rdlc file) into a foxpro database?

I already have a web based application for generating reports from a SQL Server DB but need the same reports in a foxpro DB. Is this possible? I have read that you can import crystal reports but i have seen nothing on microsoft reportviewer.

Thank you

DRomer

Comment: Can you clarify a bit - do you want to report against a VFP database using ReportViewer?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I have already built the reports using ReportViewer in Visual Studio and don't really want to spend the time designing the same reports in foxpro

Comment: Well, you can apparently use OLEDB data sources in ReportViewer so presumably you can connect to VFP using the Visual FoxPro OLEDB driver.

Comment: OK Thank you I shall try that. Thank you again :)